# Are my credentials secure if they can be console logged?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js

I'm using NextJS which, normally, involves using SSR `getStaticProps` or other methods to keep credentials on the server and off the client. I haven't been able to find a clean solution to apply that to the AWS configurations below using the normal NextJS approach. However, I did find another stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247216/how-to-setup-aws-sdk-credentials-in-nextjs) that was very relevant. I've used that SO post to build out the example shared below, however I'm concerned that I am able to `console.log` my env variables, normally if its all handled on the server those values are `undefined` on the client.

So the question is, is it safe from a security perspective to be able to log configuration variables on the client?

##### .env

```
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=example
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=example
```

##### next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    // ..others
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
};
```

##### index.js

```js
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

// logs credentials -- vulnerability?
console.log('test', config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);

AWS.config.getCredentials(err => {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  // credentials not loaded
  else {
    console.log('Access key:', AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
  }
});

const S3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Comment: You are worried rightfully, they aren't secure if they can be logged on the client. If you follow the regular next.js approach described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) you won't have this issue, that much I know. Someone with more knowledge about next.js will be able to provide more details I presume.

Comment: Side note: I don't know anything about NextJS, but I'll try to do my best in answering the question.  It matters on who can access the console.  Browser console?  If it's logged there, anyone on the internet can see it.  Backend console?  Only you can see that so it should be safe.  Just take my words with a pinch of salt, since I don't have any experience in NextJS.

Comment: But I don't understand where your index.js is supposed to execute. On the server? Then it's fine, but you mentioned it can be logged on the client, showing the log statement in this file ad reference... On the client? Then you need to rethink your approach because you aren't only logging but also _using_ them in this piece of code, which obviously can't be done from the client for the very reason you mentioned...

Comment: @CherryDT hello, the file is in the `/pages` directory within nextjs.  I've tried setting my AWS configurations with a `getStaticProps` but I'm not sure how i can return that configuration back out of the function in order to have  the configurations set correctly. If I move `AWS.config.update` into `getStaticProps` the following `AWS.config.getCredentials` logs an error.

Comment: *next.config.js is a regular Node.js module, not a JSON file. It gets used by the Next.js server and build phases, and it's not included in the browser build.* from [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction)

Comment: @James I saw that in the docs and I dont know what that means, I've built my code and I can still get the console.log back -- is that not the browser build? Could you put that in other words?

Comment: @kevin To ensure your credentials are not exposed, you should move your AWS S3 logic to an API route or `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps` methods. Here's a [sample repo](https://github.com/leerob/nextjs-aws-s3) using it. I'd also recommend you set up your env variables as described in [Next.js Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question does not have a straightforward answer and does not a have a one solution fits all.  The answer depends on your risk tolerance, hosting provider, and the AWS/3rd party services you use.

Your solution will require many readings and choices that you think are best for your application and use.

---

It is never recommended to hard-code security credentials in your code, especially for client-side code, because it is possible that they can be exposed.

I personally use [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) and federated identities with Next.js and React apps and do not have secrets in the code.  I rely on the the user's roles and permissions set via AIM roles and user pools.  My backend code also has  individual roles for every service or independent action my code calls.

*"While it is possible to do so, we do not recommend hard-coding your AWS credentials in your application. Hard-coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID and secret access key."* - [AWS SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html)

#### AWS's Security Recommendations

The first thing is to ensure that the credentials can only perform the task they are required to do (least privileged) and never use a root account.

Here are AWS's recommended [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html) when dealing with credentials.

---

#### Browser, Client-side rendering (CSR), and Static site generation (SSG)

There are a few of ways of setting your credentials for client-side code.

- Using [Amazon Cognito Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html) to authenticate users and supply credentials
- Using [web federated identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html)
- Hard coding in the script

However, AWS follows up this list up with -
*"We do not recommend hard coding your AWS credentials in your scripts. Hard coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID and secret access key."* - AWS

Here is a long list of [AWS credential recommendations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html).

---

#### API Routes, backend, and server-side rendering (SSR)

If the keys are in server-side code, it's not as big of a threat, but they could get exposed via logs or GIT, and you shouldn't put it directly in that code either.

Your current approach is certainly better than the standard .env approach however, a better solution is to use a [shared credential](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html) file for your Next.js server-side (API Routes, getStaticProps, getStaticPaths, getServerSideProps) code.

---

#### Development

Here is how to use [keys in development](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup.html#setup-credentials) mode without hard coding them in your application. This will keep the code similar for production and development as well as preventing the credentials from getting pushed into productions, logs, and code management solutions like GIT.

Every developer should have their own keys.

---

#### Environment variables

This should really be a last resort choice since AWS gives you plenty of more secure alternatives.

It would be best if you use extreme caution when placing credentials in `.env` variables.  The values get injected into code during the Next.js build processes, which could lead to your keys ending up in client-side code and logs.

Also, you should never commit .env files to code repositories.

---

#### Monitor and rotate secrets

Lastly, you can rotate and monitor your secrets using the [secrets manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_awsconfig.html).