How to use secret environmental variables through aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager in Next.js 14?
I'm trying to use environment variables stored in AWS Secrets Manager in my Next.js application, but I'm having trouble accessing them correctly. I'm using Next.js 14.
// utils/aws.js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: "ap-south-1",
});

export async function getSecret() {
    const { SecretString } = await client
        .getSecretValue({
            SecretId: "my-secret",
        })
        .promise();

    return SecretString;
}


However, when I try to run the application, I get an error
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Missing credentials in config.


The error message indicates that you're missing aws credentials. Please elaborate whether you have misconfigured in your code or its in the environment.

Actually I don't know how to it up.i didn't found the docs helpfull

See if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247216/how-to-setup-aws-sdk-credentials-in-nextjs

Thanks but this is for s3 I need for secret-manger

What you want to achieve is secret value from AWS secret manager but base on one of prerequisites is configuring aws credentials in order to use aws sdk. Google the error message to understand the root cause
